# "Again" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

What word would you use to order somebody to do something again?  I'm writing a book and know very little about the German language.  The sentence I'm trying to translate is "Again!" as in ordering someone to repeat the action.

Comment: _Noch einmal !_

Comment: asking for a translation without prior research

Answer (score 7):

»Again!« is not a sentence. It is a word with an exclamation mark. But you can interpret it as an ellipsis, which is the shortened version of a full sentence. This sentence might be:

> Do it again!

This is the verbatim translation:

> Mach es wieder!

But while the english sentence has a built-in but invisible »*now*« included, this german translation comes with a built-in and invisible »*when ever you want*«. So here is a better suitable sentence:

> Mach es noch einmal!

But this literally means:

> Do it one more time!

So it has the meaning: Do it just one more time, then it is enough. But when you say "Do it again", you often express, that you want to have it done many more times; again and again.

Here it helps to shrink down »noch einmal« to »nochmal«:

> Mach es nochmal!

Now it is as close to »do it again« as it can be made in German language, and now you can transform it to an ellipsis:

> **Nochmal!**